# How to add an attribute in xml

Tags: php, xml

I tried this php array formats.While converting to XML attributes are not getting set.

```
$request['Shopping'] = array( 
     "PTC"=>array(
     "_attributes" => array("Quantity" => "1"),
     "_value" => "ADT")
      )

function array_to_xml($array, &$xml_user_info) {
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    if(is_array($value)) {
        if(!is_numeric($key)){
            $subnode = $xml_user_info->addChild("$key");
            array_to_xml($value, $subnode);
        }else{
            $subnode = $xml_user_info->addChild("item$key");
            array_to_xml($value, $subnode);
        }
    }else {
        $xml_user_info->addChild("$key",htmlspecialchars("$value"));
    }
}
}

$xml_user_info = new SimpleXMLElement("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><user_info>      </user_info>");
array_to_xml($request,$xml_user_info);
$xml_file = $xml_user_info->asXML('users1.xml');
if($xml_file){
    echo 'XML file have been generated successfully.';
}else{
    echo 'XML file generation error.';
}
```

I need this array in below xml format

```
<PTC Quantity="1">ADT</PTC>
```

But I am getting like this.Kindly give some solution. Thanks in advance

```
    <PTC>
        <_attributes>
        <Quantity>1</Quantity>
        </_attributes>
        <_value>ADT</_value>
    </PTC>
```

Comment: show your actual code where you are processing xml structure(opening, parsing)

Comment: Is this enough @roaman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your case please use php class on the link :  http://www.lalit.org/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/Array2XML.html?ver=0.8

And use it as below code.

```
<?php
//Put above class library in same folder of below code library and include it so the class functions can be used.
include("array2xml.php");
//Format your array as below
$PTC = array(
    '@attributes' => array(
        'Quantity' => '1'
    ),
    '@value' => 'ADT',
);
$xml = Array2XML::createXML('PTC', $PTC);
echo $xml->saveXML();
?>
```

Comment: Have you checked my solution?

Comment: It's not returning proper XML format, but thank u for your ans

Comment: Have you checked the created XML in the view source after page executed. Because I had checked and it was generating the xml exactly same as you needed in question.

Comment: Please refer this link for more details. http://www.lalit.org/lab/convert-php-array-to-xml-with-attributes/